# Display database array lines whilst autoincrementing id per line

Tags: arrays, database, codeigniter, view

I wish to display the results of a database query in my view whilst giving each row a unique ID.

My model is:

```
function get_load_lines($ordernumber)
{
    $this->db->select('product,pricepercube,qty,linecost,linediscount,cubicvolume,bundles,treated,autospread');
    $this->db->from('Customer_Order_Lines');
    $this->db->where('CustomerOrderID',$ordernumber);
    $q = $this->db->get();
    if($q->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        return $q->row_array(); 
    }
}
```

My controller is:

```
function edit_order_lines() 
{
    $data = array(
        'ordernumber' =>$this->input->post('ordernumber'),
        'customer' =>$this->input->post('customer'),
        'loadlines' => $this->sales_model->get_load_lines($this->input->post('ordernumber'))
    );

    $this->load->view('sales/edit_order_lines',$data);
}
```

As mentioned I want to display each of these rows in my view.

So I use this code in my view:

```
<table>
<?php
$i=1;
foreach ($loadlines as $row)
{ 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['product']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['pricepercube']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['qty']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $i++;
}
?>
</table>
```

This does not have the intended result. `$i` increments for each array entry, not each array line.

Any advice on the best way to display this data?

So if 3 rows the below is required:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model, try returning a `result_array`, rather than a `row_array`:

```
return $q->result_array();
```

If more than one result exists, *result array* will return all of the results, whereas *row array* will only return one. CodeIgniter's [user guide explains the differences](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html).

You could also make your *for loop* at little bit tidier, by incrementing `$i` like this:

```
$i=1;
foreach ($loadlines as $row)
{ 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$i++."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['product']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['pricepercube']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['qty']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Champion, works perfectly. Appreciate your time and knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand you question clearly, but in order to edit Customer Order Line (order details) you should also pull the ID of each Customer_Order_Lines when you query the database. (assuming your table Customer_Order_Lines has primary key filed called ID).

```
 $this->db->select('id,product,pricepercube,q...');
```

Then when you loop through the results, do:

```
foreach ($loadlines as $row)
           { 
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['product']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['pricepercube']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['qty']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
$i++;
           }
```

This will give you the specific unique ID's (primary keys) of each Order Line. Then, you can updated each Order Line by referring to this ID.

Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks Marko, works perfectly however I needed to correct the `return $q->result_array();` as well as per `Lefters` answer. Appreciate your time...

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer promptly. Cheers!